# font-icons.woff 404 not found with micro frontend

Tags: css, angular, web-component

I'm developing a micro frontend, for this I use Webpack 5 Module Federation and ngx-build-plus builder on an Angular 14 application.

When I build my project I get the following files:

```html
dist
├── my-webco
│   ├── 106.js
│   ├── 136.js
│   ├── 497.js
│   ├──    .
│   ├──    .
│   ├──    .
│   ├── icon-font.woff
│   ├── icon-font.woff2
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── remoteEntry.js
│   ├── style.css
```

So I want to import the main.js file into another application this way:

```html
<script src="https://my-host/my-webco/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<my-web-component></my-web-component>
```

The webcomponent works well but I have a 404 error on the font because my font is on the path "https://my-host/my-webco/font-icons.woff" and my application will load it on the path "https://my-host/font-icons.woff".

do you know where I can set up this path?